# How to find a cell with any value and then find the next value that is different in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, find, copy-paste

I have a list of data with various different columns.

What I am trying to achieve is for excel to look through one of the columns and find the first value that occurs, copy that cell and then paste it in another cell. The data starts in row three (Rows 1 and 2 are headers). Let's say I want to paste the first value in G3.

Then, I need excel to find the next value that is different from the first in the same column and perform the same action as before: copy the value, and paste it in the next row in column G.

I have tried coding this but I'm not getting anywhere with it, and I haven't found a way to find a cell and then the next cell if the value within the cell is not defined (as the .Find function requires a value to search for). I know how to code the copy/paste functions but I cannot figure out how to get it to find the cell in the first place.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: `Sub createnextlink()  
Dim list As Range  
'find first value  
list = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")  
list.find(What:=list.value, Lookin:=list)  
ActiveCell.copy  
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1000").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial  
  
'find next value  
'?????  

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

In this sample, we are looking for values in column **A**:

```
Sub FillG()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Rows.Count

   Range("A3:A" & i).Copy Range("G3:G" & i)
   ActiveSheet.Range("G3:G" & i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
   If Range("G3").Value = "" Then Range("G3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

The method is to copy all of column **A** to **G**, then remove duplicates, then remove an empty in **G3** if it exists.:

[image]

Comment: Hi @garys-student . I have tried putting this into vba and sadly it doesn't work. I can see what is trying to be done here but In column G, I'm getting x,x,x,y,z,y,z in each row going down. Any suggestions?

Comment: @maxthackray  **What version of Excel are you using ??**

Comment: @garys-student Excel 2016 on Mac

Comment: @maxthackray  I do not know if `RemoveDuplicates` is available on that version....

Comment: @garys-student It does appear to be available but it doesn't seem to work. What it is doing is pasting the values that are in Column A into Column G but one row up. I have a feeling that this is because the code only specifies to delete cell G3 if it is empty, but that may be completely wrong